# Google Sheets SQL Queries Timing Out

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, google-sheets

I have several google sheets, both ones I've created and ones that were inherited that are experiencing repeated timeouts even when trying to run simple queries.  Most of these sheets worked just fine until late last week.  For example, the query below is run by one of the sheets I've inherited.  It returns 5 rows and runs instantly on our sql client (SSMS).  However, it is timing out every single time when run in sheets.

```
select rtrim(d.brand) [brand]
, rtrim(d.partno) [partno]
,rtrim(d.descrip) [description],
case when ts.Score is null then 'B' else ts.Score end [score]
, sum(d.qtyord) [Qty] 
from PoDetail d  
left join WarehouseTrafficScore ts 
on ts.partno = d.partno 
and ts.brand = d.brand 
where d.ponumb in ('98-1899','98-1900') 
group by d.brand, d.partno, d.descrip, ts.Score 
having sum(d.qtyord) > 0 
order by brand, partno
```

Below is the sheets script code that is calling this:

```
function menuItem1() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetIdhere')
    ,ssdash = doc.getSheetByName('dashboard')
    ,sspo = doc.getSheetByName('PoList')
    ,ssrec = doc.getSheetByName('Receiver')
    ,receiver
    ,polist = sspo.getRange('A2:A'+ sspo.getLastRow()).getValues()
    ;

  // Remove protections from dashboard and receiver so as to print new data.
  protectSheet(ssdash,false);
  protectSheet(ssrec,false);

  ssdash.getRange('B2:B5').clearContent();

  receiver = pullReceiverManual(doc,ssdash,ssrec,false);

  printReceiver(doc,polist.join(','),receiver);

  // Add protections back to dashboard and receiver after printing data.
  protectSheet(ssdash,true);
  protectSheet(ssrec,true);
}

// Pull receiver data based on list of POs from PO list. Passing GoogleDoc, dashboard spreadsheet, receiver spreadsheet and list of po numbers. Returns receiver result set.
function pullReceiverManual(doc,ssdash,ssrec,manual_tf) {
  var range = ssdash.getRange('A2');
  var start = new Date();

  // Establish connnection with server and print error to dashboard if failure.
  try{
      var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("connectionstring","user","password");
      conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    } catch(e2){
      range.offset(0,1).setValue(e2);
    };

  // Create qry statement and print error to dashboard if error.
  try{
      var stmt = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (e3) {
      range.offset(1,1).setValue(e3);
    };

  // Define the query. If manual = true, the query will pull based on brands and partnumbers listed on the Manual Receiver page. Otherwise, it will use POs.
  if(manual_tf) {
    var ssman = doc.getSheetByName('ManualReceiver');
    var data = ssman.getRange('A2:C'+ssman.getLastRow());
    var str = "";

      for(a = 1; a <= data.getNumRows(); a++) {
          str += data.getCell(a, 1).getValue() + "','" + data.getCell(a, 2).getValue()  + "'," + data.getCell(a, 3).getValue();
        if (a < data.getNumRows()) {str += "),('"};
      };

    Logger.log(str)
    var qryIn = "create table #temp(" +
              "brand varchar(3)," +
              "partno varchar(20)," +
              "qty int);" +

              "insert into #temp values " +
              "('" + str + "); ";

    var qry = "select rtrim(d.brand) [brand],rtrim(d.partno) [partno],rtrim(i.[Description]) [description],case when ts.Score is null then 'B' else ts.Score end [score],sum(d.qty) [Qty] " +
              "from #temp d " +
                "left join ItemData i on i.brand = d.brand and i.partno = d.partno " +
                "left join WarehouseTrafficScore ts on ts.partno = d.partno and ts.brand = d.brand " +
              "group by d.brand,d.partno,i.[Description],ts.Score " +
              "having sum(d.qty) > 0 " +
              "order by brand, partno";

    // Print query to the dashboard for error checking and reference.
    range.offset(2,1).setValue(qryIn+qry);

    // Run query.
    stmt.executeUpdate(qryIn);

  } else {
    var sspo = doc.getSheetByName('PoList'),
      polist = sspo.getRange('A2:A'+ sspo.getLastRow()).getValues();

    var qry = "select rtrim(d.brand) [brand], rtrim(d.partno) [partno],rtrim(d.descrip) [description],case when ts.Score is null then 'B' else ts.Score end [score], sum(d.qtyord) [Qty] " +
              "from PoDetail d  " +
                "left join WarehouseTrafficScore ts on ts.partno = d.partno and ts.brand = d.brand " +
              "where d.ponumb in ('" + polist.join("','") + "') " +
              "group by d.brand, d.partno, d.descrip, ts.Score " +
              "having sum(d.qtyord) > 0 " +
              "order by brand, partno";

    // Print query to the dashboard for error checking and reference.
    range.offset(2,1).setValue(qry);
  };

  // Execute query and retrieve result set to pass into print function. Print error to dashboard if failure.
  try{  
    var result = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
  } catch (e4) {
    range.offset(3,1).setValue(e4);
  };

  return result

  result.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
```

I'm not the most familiar with sheets script, but I was able to verify the actual connection string is correct, and both the coded error trapping and running in debug mode indicate that the query is timing out.  Is there some limitation we're running into with Google, or do I need to talk to our database people about something on their end?  Again, this is happening on multiple sheets, this is just an extreme example of 5 rows of data supposedly timing out.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC on Google Apps Script. Exception: Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314840/jdbc-on-google-apps-script-exception-statement-cancelled-due-to-timeout-or-cli)

Comment: Yes, setting the runtime version back did fix the issue!  Thanks.  I'll dig into that link and see about migrating all my scripts to V8 for the future.